# In tsql how to select records based on even or uneven dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to be able to select records based on even or uneven dates.

I have a table with 4 columns and one has the sign up date and I would like to segment them into two groups based on their sign up dates (using the day as the denominator). So 12/4/2013 would be in the even and 4/3/2012 in the uneven.

I am not sure how to construct this query, I was looking at the datepart but wasn't sure if there is something more straight forward.

thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reproduce the issue using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: `DATEAPART(dd, your_date)` should give you date and then use % to find if it is even or not.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT signed_on, DAY(signed_on) % 2 AS uneven
FROM YourTable
```

`uneven` will be either `0` or `1`

```
SELECT DAY('2013-01-03') % 2 -- 1
SELECT DAY('2013-01-02') % 2 -- 0
```

If you want to name your column **even** rather than **uneven** you could just inverse the result.

```
SELECT signed_on, POWER(DAY(signed_on) % 2 - 1, 2) AS even
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

HINT (for now unless you can show you've tried something yourself) You could do something like `DATEPART(day, date) % 2` with a case statement (case statement isn't necessary, but could be if you want to easily go between even and uneven without changing the query of course depending on your environment).

Answer (score 0):

`DATEPART(dd, your_date)` should give you the date part of your date and then use % to find if it is even or not in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should be straight forward -

```
SELECT COL,CASE WHEN DAY(COL)%2=0 THEN 'EVEN' ELSE 'UNEVEN' END AS [EVEN_UNEVEN]
FROM TEST
```

Sample output from my sample table-

```
COL                     EVEN_UNEVEN
2014-01-09 22:39:51.203 UNEVEN
2014-01-10 22:39:51.210 EVEN
2014-01-12 22:39:51.210 EVEN
2014-01-13 22:39:51.213 UNEVEN
```

Comment: Suyash I was able to complete the query with your answer. I knew I could use the datepart function but wasn't sure if you could use the %.